# use-package and straight.el: can't load a package that exists locally?

Tags: init-file, use-package, straight.el

I'm using the awesome use-package and the awesome straight.el to manage packages.

I'd like to use xahk-mode.  I've checked in the 'repos' directory of straight and I **can** see a folder named xahk-mode so I think it's locally available to straight.el.

However, when I try to execute

```
(use-package xahk-mode)
```

I get the error message:

```
Error (use-package): Cannot load xahk-mode
```

I'm using use-package and straight.el to load packages elsewhere (successfully), and I've got these in my config file:

```
(straight-use-package 'use-package)
(setq straight-use-package-by-default t)
```

The error message that I'm seeing doesn't make a whole lot of sense - is there any way to get more detailed information about what went wrong?  (And/or - does anyone have any advice on what to look for / try in order to fix this?)

Comment: I have just tried it and it works without problems on my computer.

Comment: Is the directory in your `C-h v load-path` ?

Comment: @phils - yes.  In fact, it's first.

Comment: @serycjon - Thanks for the confirmation!  I'm pretty confident this is something I messed up all by myself - I'm mostly looking for advice on how to figure out _what_ I messed up :)

Comment: Without really guessing at what the issue might be, I would try (1) M-x straight-pull-package / straight-rebuild-package and variants, (2) deleting that folder on disk and re-launching Emacs with your `use-package` in place in your init config, (3) deleting the entire repos folder and restarting Emacs.